# ASP.NET - Are there any advantages or differences in using (Type)Container.DataItem and Eval() within Server tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Are there any advantages or differences between using the following?

```
<%# Eval("Item.Details")%>
```

and `<%# ((ItemDetails)Container.DataItem).Item.Details%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there aren't any. The second is a bit better as it is strongly typed but might still crash at runtime if the cast fails.

In [ASP.NET vNext](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/09/01/strongly-typed-data-controls-asp-net-vnext-series.aspx) you will be able to do this directly:

```
<%# Item.Details %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the second approach is that it is type-safe and can therefore be checked at compile time using aspnet_compiler (useful if, for example, your data model changes).

You can even encapsulate the cast of the DataItem to your ItemDetails class in a function in the code-behind file and avoid repetitive type casts, as I sketched in a [blog post](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/type-safe-databindings-in-asp-net/).